# SWTOR Launch Problems

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Every time I press the play button on the launch screen, the launcher closes but the game never shows up. I've tried all the things Bio-ware suggested. I've even tried some of the stuff other people have suggested to no avail. What should I do?

Comment: Have you updated the game? Can you start with the lowest graphic settings? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me on several installs:

1. Add `launcher.exe`, `fixlauncher.exe`, and `swtor.exe` to your antivirus and firewall whitelists.
2. Configure all 3 to run as Administrator and compatibility mode for the next lowest Windows version — i.e., Windows 7 SP1 if you're running Windows 8/8.1. You do this in Properties for the executable.
3. Reboot.
4. Run FixLauncher.
5. Run the launcher.  Leave it while it updates and restarts itself.
6. Login and play!